# tailwindcss utility class not working laravel 9 when uploaded to host

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, vite

When in development everything runs without any problems, but when in production tailwindcss does not work

**@vite**

```
@vite('resources/css/app.css')
```

Becomes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.mh**.com/build/assets/app.2d284f54.css" />
```

**resouces/css/app.css**

```js
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kanit:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


*
*
*
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

**public/build/minifest.json**

```js
{
  "resources/js/app.js": {
    "file": "assets/app.334e7359.js",
    "src": "resources/js/app.js",
    "isEntry": true
  },
  "resources/css/app.css": {
    "file": "assets/app.2d284f54.css",
    "src": "resources/css/app.css",
    "isEntry": true
  }
}
```

**npm run build**

```js
$ npm run build

> build
> vite build

vite v3.1.3 building for production...
✓ 58 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json             0.25 KiB
public/build/assets/app.2d284f54.css   23.11 KiB / gzip: 5.07 KiB
public/build/assets/app.334e7359.js    90.63 KiB / gzip: 33.07 KiB
```

Comment: do you see `public` in your page URLs ?

Comment: in the root url there is a public which contains the build folder, is that what you mean?

Comment: No in your page URLs.  I'm trying to establish if you have the correct _document root_

Comment: I think I have the correct document root, where my document root is **public_html/mh**.com/portfolio**

Comment: seems unlikely. Your document root should be your public folder.  This means that `/build` references the assets and does not need to be `/public/build`

Comment: It looks like it's not possible, because when doing `npm run build` is automatically created a **public** folder containing the **build** folder, if the **build** folder is moved to root then an error occurs `Vite manifest not found at: /home/bpebcnvv/public_html/mh**/portofolio/public/build/manifest.json`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: All your problems stem from not hosting your site correctly and trying to find workarounds.